# How to store javascript background color change in a session

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a web based game which has 6 different background colours which alternate throughout. When the button is pressed on the page it then sets a new colour on the next page. However if the page is refreshed it reverts back to the original colour. I know that I need to store the colours in a session so that this doesn't happen, but unfortunately I am struggling to do this as I am new to JavaScript and everything I have tried so far doesn't work.

This is the JavaScript I currently have:

```
<script>
    function backgroundYellow() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F7B538";
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function backgroundBlue() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#3CB9C4";
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function backgroundPink() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#C33C55";
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function backgroundGreen() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#8CB369";
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function backgroundOrange() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#E57A44";
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function backgroundPurple() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#606CA8";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: just a fyi you don't need separate script tags for each function, you could have just one set around all the functions

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay at only aiming this at HTML5 enabled browsers then I would suggest Local Storage. You can store name-value pairs in the browser itself. Here's a pretty good way to start: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Example:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

If you want to go down the route of using sessions then your should look into adding server side functionality into your game - PHP might be best if you're a beginner.

Comment: @depperm - can you please post your example in your own answer, and it would be better I think to let OP learn Local Storage themselves since it may play quite a large part in their game.

Comment: Don't just provide a link to a reference, usually its a good idea to provide an example, links may not work in the future

Comment: Fair point about the example but yours was more of a full solution, what I have edited above is more of an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using local storage, something like this should work

html

```
<body onload="revertColor()">
```

js

```
function revertColor(){
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage
    if (localStorage.getItem("backgroundColor") === null) 
      document.body.style.backgroundColor=localStorage.getItem("backgroundColor");
     else//background is not set-local storage enabled/exists
       backgroundYellow();//or default color
  } else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
    backgoundYellow();//or default color function
  }
}

//for your color functions
funtion backgoundYellow(){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#606CA8";
  localStorage.setItem("backgroundColor", "#606CA8");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this didn't work for me